# Storing values in array or additional table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database, database-design

I'm developing a booking system in rails 5.1 for hotels, whereas the price per night depends on the duration of a stay. Ok, so basically this is a question related to database design and I would like your opinion on which option to go with:

**Option A:** I just go ahead and save the prices in my *Room* table in an array, so that:

```
price_increments = [1_day,2_days,...,n_days] = [80,65,...,x]
```

I could then access this array by passing the duration of stay, so that:

```
def booking
    days = (end_date - start_date).to_i
    price = price_increments.at(days)
    total = price * days
end
```

**Option B:** I create an additional table for prices, but then I wouldn't be quite sure how to access the respective price with regards to the duration, especially since the application is supposed to be a platform with multiple hotels?

What do you think? Is it save to go with Option A or shall I try to go with Option B? What would be considered to be best practice? Any advice appreciated:)

Comment: _"how to access the respective price with regards to the duration"_ – just store the price along with the duration, i.e `price: 80, days: 1`, `price: 65, days: 2` etc.

Comment: As in creating an additional table like described in Option B? But yes, you're right. This ways I could easily access the prices as well.

Comment: Would the corresponding query be like :
price = Price.where("room_ID  = ? AND days = ?, params[:room_ID], params[:duration])

Comment: As far as best practice, it's usually better to have more tables than to use serialized columns because it lets your database do the work. As an example - A user wants a 5 night stay but they don't want to pay more than 50 per night. With Option A you need to instantiate every record to be able to check its 5-night price, whereas with Option B you can do it with one SQL query.

Comment: Also, If you use database to store prices, In future you can be able to give a UI to update the prices.

Comment: @Luke You can write that as `Price.where(room_id: params[:room_id], days: params[:duration])` - you don't need to write it in the SQL form. EDIT: although it might be better to set it up as an association on the room model, so you can just do `room.prices.where(days: params[:duration])`

Comment: Got it, totally makes sense! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

For a good reason you should develop your logic price_increments record: we need to know if it's a regular price or with major.
Any way i think it's a possible to do your opération before saving record in a singular table with `before_save`

```
def Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :init
    PRICE_INCREMENT = [one, two, three, four]

    def init
        self.duration ||= (end_date - start_date).to_i
        self.price    ||= duration * PRICE_INCEREMENT[duration]
    end
 end
```